# What is the reason for getting this rendering error after passing data to this ReactTable component?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, material-ui, react-table

This is the parent component that has columns array and data array.

```
const TransactionTable = () => {
  const columns = useMemo(
      () => [
        {
          Header: 'DATE/TIME',
          accessor: 'date'
        },
        {
          Header: 'TYPE',
          accessor: 'type'
        },
        {
          Header: 'AMOUNT',
          accessor: 'amount'
        },
        {
          Header: 'Status',
          accessor: 'status'
        }
      ],[]
  )

    const data = useMemo(
        () => [
        {
            date: '1681038120',
            type: 'Credit',
            amount: '4500',
            status: 'processing'
        }
    ], [])
    return (
      <ReactTable columns={columns} data={data}/>
  )
```

This is the ReactTable component that have implemented using react-table and MaterialUI.

```
import {Stack, Table, TableBody, TableCell, TableHead, TableRow} from "@mui/material";
import {Cell, Column, HeaderGroup, Row, useTable} from "react-table";

const ReactTable = ({columns, data}: {columns: Column[]; data: any}) => {

    const {getTableProps,getTableBodyProps, headerGroups, rows, prepareRow} = useTable({columns, data});

  return (
      <Stack>
          <Table {...getTableProps()}>
              <TableHead>
                  {headerGroups.map((headerGroup) => (
                      <TableRow {...headerGroup.getHeaderGroupProps()}>
                          {headerGroup.headers.map((column: HeaderGroup) => (
                              <TableCell {...column.getHeaderProps()} align='center'>{column.render('Header')}</TableCell>
                          ))}
                      </TableRow>
                  ))}
              </TableHead>
              <TableBody {...getTableBodyProps()}>
              {rows.map((row:Row) => {
                  prepareRow(row);
                   return (
                       <TableRow {...row.getRowProps()}>
                           {row.cells.map((cell: Cell)=> (
                               <TableCell {...cell.getCellProps()}>{cell.render('cell')}</TableCell>
                           ))}
                       </TableRow>
                   )
                  }
              )}
              </TableBody>
          </Table>
      </Stack>
  )
}
export default ReactTable;
```

This is the error that shown after passing data array to the ReactTable component.
[image]

When data array is empty as below it will render without any problem. but when after passing some data to the array it will throw that error.

```
<ReactTable columns={columns} data={[]}/>
```

Comment: Error-dump indicates that error is close to either `headerGroup.headers.map` or `row.cells.map`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to debug the code but could not find the root cause by looking at the logs. So I started comparing the [official docs example](https://react-table-v7.tanstack.com/docs/quick-start#applying-the-table-instance-to-markup) and found out that there is a typo in your code.

```
<TableCell {...cell.getCellProps()}>{cell.render('cell')}</TableCell>
```

should be

```
<TableCell {...cell.getCellProps()}>{cell.render('Cell')}</TableCell>
```

Notice `cell.render('Cell')` having capital `C` in `Cell`